# Holomorphic Vector Bundle and Non-Degenerate Pairing

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

By Daniel Huybrechts in **Complex Geometry**, we have:

> For any holomorphic vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$ there exists a non-degenerate pairing $$\bigwedge^{k}E \times \bigwedge^{r-k}E \longrightarrow \text{det}(E)$$ that induces a isomorphism of holomorphic vector bundles $$\bigwedge^{k}E \simeq \bigwedge^{r-k}E^{*} \otimes \text{det}(E)$$

Can someone give me a reference where I find the demonstration of this result?

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you understand the corresponding statement(s) for vector spaces? Can you explain what you're not getting? Thanks

Comment: Peter. I am trying to use the theorem 4.11 of (http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/bundleops.pdf). Thanks.

Comment: It is easy to get the pairing between the fibers, but how I get the result for the holomorphic vector bundles? What is the definition of a pairing of vector bundles?